# Bootstrap classes for positioning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What class i need to use to place second button on the same line with first button. I am using bootstrap 4. [image]

```
<div class="container">

           <div class="row justify-content-sm-center">

               <div class="col-sm-5 kappa">

                   <h3>Don't have an account?</h3>
                   <hr>
                   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem quasi facere officiis numquam alias, delectus beatae autem facilis aliquid voluptates aspernatur, eaque suscipit possimus eveniet praesentium explicabo itaque nulla distinctio.
                   </p>
                   <button type="button">sign up</button>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-5 kappa">
                   <h3>Have an account?</h3>
                   <hr>
                   <p>
                       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit!
                   </p>
                   <button type="button" class="">login</button>
               </div>

           </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Show html and css you have.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no code provided, assuming you are using Bootstrap 4 and apply flexbox css, in Bootstrap 4 the class is call `.d-flex`. After you apply `.d-flex` to parent all the direct descendant can be align easily using `margin`. In Bootstrap 4 it is call `mt-auto` and `mb-0`.

```css
.bigcontainer{

height:300px;
background:grey;
width:40%;
float:left;
margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="bigcontainer d-flex flex-column">
  <div>Title</div>
  <div>Sed orci purus, porta ac feugiat ut, tincidunt vel libero. Aenean ultricies porta magna in ultricies. Fusce vitae felis augue.Quisque semper eleifend odio eget feugiat. Curabitur id mi tristique, ultrices lectus quis, gravida tortor..</div>
  <div class="mt-auto mb-0"><button>button</button></div>
</div>

<div class="bigcontainer d-flex flex-column">
  <div>Title</div>
  <div>Sed orci purus, porta ac feugiat ut, tincidunt vel libero. Aenean ultricies porta magna in ultricies. Fusce vitae felis augue. </div>
  <div class="mt-auto mb-0"><button>button</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to do the same, but my button became full width wide

Comment: can you show your preview code in another page like codepen or jsfiddle?

Comment: It's ok already, I found solution for that, I aligned items to start and then gave button mt-auto class, but now i need to move only that button to the center(not whole div) just button

Comment: try apply css `text-align: center;` to the button

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
        .cs-button {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        </style>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="height: 200px;">
                  <div>Title</div>
                  <div>Sed orci purus, porta ac feugiat ut, tincidunt vel libero. Aenean ultricies porta magna in ultricies. Fusce vitae felis augue.Quisque semper eleifend odio eget feugiat. Curabitur id mi tristique, ultrices lectus quis, gravida tortor..</div>
                  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 cs-button" style="padding:0" >
                    <div class="mt-auto mb-0"><button>button</button></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="height: 200px;">
                  <div>Title</div>
                  <div>Sed orci purus, porta ac feugiat ut, tincidunt vel libero. Aenean ultricies porta magna in ultricies. Fusce vitae felis augue. </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 cs-button" style="padding:0">
                    <div class="mt-auto mb-0"><button>button</button></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```